# Show Fragment like a popup with a Transparent background

Tags: android, popup, fragment, alert

I would like to make a `Fragment` pop-up like an `AlertDialog` but with a transparent background.

My fragment looks like this:

[image]

At the moment I am doing the following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Player player = (Player)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(PlayerProfileFragment.newInstance(null), null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

The fragment doesn't show at all. I guess in order to make it work, I should use the overload `add(layoutId, fragment)` but that would just place the Fragment in a specific area and not display the Fragment as a "popup".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `Fragment` probably doesn't show because you are not specifying to which layout you want to add it to. The version of [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) that you are using, adds the `Fragment` to a container whose id is 0 as the docs say.

Comment: Right ok. So how do I make it popup like a dialog and make it centered? So that it's sitting above the current fragment which is fullscreen.

Comment: Just to give you a heads up. If you `add()` one `Fragment` on top of another `Fragment`, white spaces on the top most `Fragment` will not capture click events. This means that if you have clickable components  below the white space, the will trigger. You can easily animate `FragmentTransactions` with the `setCustomAnimation()`.

Comment: If you want to center the `Fragment` you can create an empty,transparent, and centered `ViewGroup`and then add your `Fragment` to it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Could you please show some code?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating an interface with the method:

`public void addFragment(int viewId, Fragment fragment);`

I then implemented that listener in my Activity by having a `FragmentTransaction` inside it:

```
public void addFragment(int viewId, Fragment fragment){ 
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentTransaction().beginTran....;
    fragmentTransaction.add(viewId, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```